# Google Chrome: "Experiments are oversubscribed in layer: GvnExternalLayer. Fraction: 1.1400000000000001"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, warnings

I'm responsible for developing an enterprise JavaScript video player application, and I've begun noticing this new warning message in Google Chrome's web console when using my JavaScript:

```
Experiments are oversubscribed in layer: GvnExternalLayer. Fraction: 1.1400000000000001
```

Has anyone else begun noticing this? I am running the latest version of Chrome, Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) on OS X Yosemite, and can find absolutely no references to this warning message when searching online.

I like to understand all warning messages that come across the web console when possible. Can someone give me some context here or even point me in the right direction to look this up?

EDIT: I notice that I'm seeing this in Firefox v38.0.5 as well, and so I do not believe it is tied to an automatic Google Chrome update.

Comment: I got the same warning on my site. This is the only existence of the error on google when using quotes. There is a try catch in my inspect element. Not sure how or why.